# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found for viewer.js when publishing application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express, pdf.js

I have tested the application using viewer.js with Visual studio internal web server(IIS Express) and it is working fine.If for instance I try to browse `http://internallocalhost/Viewer.JS/index.html/#`  it works fine
But when i published the application on IIS i am getting 404 error at the address

```
http://publishedsite/Viewer.JS/index.html/#
```

it works fine if it is like `http://publishedsite/Viewer.JS/index.html` but it is of no use as i have to concatenate the url of my pdf file like

```
http://publishedsite/Viewer.JS/index.html/#http://publishedsite/mytest.pdf
```

Any particular settings required on IIS? 
Can't understand how IIS Express not able to reproduce same error.

Comment: because index.html is not a folder or script?

Comment: IIS Express might be configured to understand html resources as a script

Comment: Can i do that some how for my particular asp.net application?

Comment: see what handler is assigned for .aspx and assign the same for .html. btw, why it's pdf.js question? can you replicate that with any index.html page?

Comment: didn't try out that way. Actually there is no viewer.js tag and internally viewer.js uses pdf.js .So i thought some one else has also experience the problem and might help in it